# Реализация хранения, чтения и записи настроек, PHP

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток товарищи! В свободное время продолжаю писать свою CMS систему, было много версий системы (около 12-и) и с каждой новой версией добавлялся функционал и увеличивалось быстродействие, однако вот в чём беда :

Системе нужно хранить настройки, в главном файле их читать и использовать, а в админке - читать и изменять.

Пробовал хранить настройки в XML файлах всё хорошо, однако быстродействие заметно падало.

*Какие существуют способы **хранения и записи** "настроек" без использования БД?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Классический вариант хранения "настроек" - ini-файлы.
2. Сериализация некого массива настроек и запись в файл.
3. А еще в файл можно записать собственно сам php-код с массивом настроек.
4. PEAR::Config - но это XML, можно вычеркнуть.

В общем, вся задача - что-то в файл записать, что-то из него считать. Если XML для Вас долго - значит Вы либо гуру оптимизации и бьетесь за каждый килобайт памяти (что похвально), либо перегружаете XML-парсер кривыми регулярками.

Попробуйте ini - достаточно удобно.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ini

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Я рассматривал такой вариант и остановился было на нём, но есть ли какие нибудь стандартные средства в PHP для записи(изменения) значений?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю словосочетание "стандартные средства" в контексте вопроса. Хотите аналог реестра MS Windows? Такого нет. Но готовых библиотек для работы с конфигами очень много, и большинство работает именно с XML.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!)